# You are an intellectual workhouse

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wan't to know the nuance of "intellectual workhouse".

This is from Astrology character analysis.
Whole paragraph is this.

"The inconjunct between Mercury and Uranus shows that you endure severe punishment in attempting to serve the world at large.
You are an intellectual workhouse, and your serenity is constantly disturbed by the problems of others.
You work in hesitant spurts of enthusiasm followed by periods of mental anguish for not completing what you start."

I think, maybe, "workhouse" is this.

- (in the UK) a public institution in which the destitute of a parish received board and lodging in return for work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You **must** tell us where a quotation comes from!

Comment: It's a nonstandard usage, meaning someone with lots of intellectual energy. "intellectual powerhouse" would be a more common term.

Answer (score 2):

According to Merriam-Webster, a [workhouse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workhouse) is:

> a house of correction for persons guilty of minor law violations

That seems unlikely. I suspect that this is a typo for **powerhouse** or **workhorse.**

A [powerhouse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/powerhouse) is defined by Merriam-Webster as:

> one having great drive, energy, or ability

A [workhorse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workhorse) is defined by Merriam-Webster as:

> a hardworking person

"Powerhouse" seems more sensible in context, but "workhouse" and "workhorse" are only one letter apart, making a typo more likely.